# URL Scheme app name missing from alert: Open this page in ""

Tags: ios, ios8, safari

I created a URL Scheme to open my app from a web browser e.g. AppName:// , It successfully opens the app, but my app name is missing from the alert that prompts the user from Safari
The alert message is "Open this page in ""?"
I would like it to say "Open this page in AppName"

Thank you

Comment: Did you set the relevant parameters in your app plist?

Comment: Thanks Mark can you specify exactly which param is relevant here? Not sure myself. thanks

Comment: check out this http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: Yes I have the same params set as specified in that article

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this. In case anyone else is looking for the answer, Safari pulls the app's **Bundle Display Name** for this alert which you can set in the Info.plist

Comment: I set bundle display name. Still its showing the alert. Could u please elaborate the answer?

Comment: @AugustinePA I hope you have this figured out by now, but this doesn't cause the alert to show or not show. It simply gets the app's name into the alert.

Comment: I don't know why, but alert show `BundleName` instead of `BundleDisplayName` in title

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by just specify you url like this[image]